# How to run script on interface up/down?

Tags: networking, fedora

I want to connect to VPN every time `eth0` goes up. I have already a script to do connect to VPN. How can I run it on interface up event on Fedora Core 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on Fedora 11, the networking scripts will call `/sbin/ifup-local ${DEVICE}` after bringing up the interfaces.  Does that do what you're wanting?

(Note: untested)

Comment: Thanks, it works. But is it the proper way to edit `/sbin/ifup-local` itself? Is there any config file in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` for this purpose?

Comment: On my F11 system, /sbin/ifup-local doesn't exist.  What package does it belong to on yours?  (`rpm -qf /sbin/ifup-local`)

Comment: It doesn't exist on mine to. But I wrote a simple script and after `service network restart` it is called three times: with `eth0`, `wlan0` and `lo` as parameters.

Comment: Then yeah, that looks like the way they intend it to be done.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of VPN is it?  If you use NetworkManager you can set a VPN to automatically connect itself (For desktop use especially, NM is the recommended form of networking to use on Fedora)

Comment: I've tried setting this, and at least on F11, it doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: I don't want to use NM. I had bad experience with it in F10 and I don't understand what it can afford me on my one-interface system.